# Open image in new window in mako template

Tags: javascript, mako

How can I open an image (with an url which is a mako variable) in a new window inside a mako template? I would like the simplest thing possible. This is what I'm trying to use:

```
<script>
function openImage(image_url) {
  window.open('_blank').document.write('<img src="' + image_url + '">');
}
</script>

<a href="#"><img src="${image_overview_url}" onclick="openImage(${image_to_open_url});"></a>
```

However, no new window opens with the code above... Any other options how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try putting quotes around your image url in your onclick attribute.  I have replaced `openImage(${image_to_open_url})` with `openImage('${image_to_open_url}')`.  I don't think it can bare as you have it.

```
<script>
function openImage(image_url) {
  window.open('_blank').document.write('<img src="' + image_url + '">');
}
</script>

<a href="#"><img src="${image_overview_url}" onclick="openImage('${image_to_open_url}');"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the reference to the picture in the link and a `target="_blank"` it should work.

```
<a href="${image_overview_url}" target="_blank"><img src="${image_overview_url}"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing opens. It seems simple code/case so I just don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: it might be something to do with the ${image_overview_url}

Comment: try doing it with a url that you now is a picture